# How to show video controls after first click on the video?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a few videos on my html site and I want them to be showen with a poster (thumbnail). The controls should only be visible when the user clicks on the video for the first time. So when the user visits the page, the controls should be hidden an when the user clicks on the video the controls should be visible.

This is the js I tried (is in the header tag):

```
<script>
      document.getElementById("video1").addEventListener("click", setAttribute("controls", "true"));
    </script>
```

And this is my html:

```
<div class="container1">
  <video src="Videos/Film 1.mp4" poster="Thumbnails/Film 1.jpg" class="video1" id="video1"> 
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: `setAttribute` isn't a global function but a method on an HTML element, also you need to pass a function to be called later and not call it right away. For example: `document.getElementById("video1").addEventListener("click", e => e.target.setAttribute("controls", "true"));`

Comment: Please may you read through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener especially the examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `setAttribute` is **not** a part of `Window` object. It is a part of a specified element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

You have to select the element using `geElementById`/`geElementsByClassName` or etc..

In this case, You can get element from `event.target` since you want to select the element which is the origin of the event.

```js
document.getElementById("video1").addEventListener(
    "click",
    (event) => event.target.setAttribute("controls", "true")
);
```

```css
.video1 {
  background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <video src="Videos/Film 1.mp4" poster="Thumbnails/Film 1.jpg" class="video1" id="video1"> 
  </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used the callback function of event listener wrong. Thats why it was not working

Also you need to place your script in end of html body.

```html
<div class="container1">
  <video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4" poster="Thumbnails/Film 1.jpg" class="video1" id="video1"> 
  </video>
</div>
<script>
const videoElement = document.getElementById("video1");
videoElement.removeAttribute("controls");
    videoElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
    videoElement.setAttribute("controls", "true");
    videoElement.play();
 });
    </script>
```